# PHP Framework: OctoberCMS - Variable Scope Confusion

Tags: php, variables, scope, twig, octobercms

I am trying to make an app by using this framework / CMS: October CMS. I am reading the [documentation](https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/templating) and I can't find what I want to accomplish; it says:

> The {% set %} tag can be used to set variables inside the template.
>
> {% **set activePage = 'blog'** %}

I want to add an optional partial, or by default add it in the layout if a variable is true in the Home page. In Blade templating, you can use just `@yield('partial')` and by not doing that would not throw an exception, in Twig templating it does. So I did the following:

In the **layout.htm** file:

```
{% set flipbook = true %}
... some code
```

In the **home.htm** which is using that layout:

```
{% if flipbook %}
   {% partial 'partial' %}
{% endif %}
... some code
```

**The issue:** The partial is not being included and it refers to the variable which is not in the same variable scope. I know that refers to the scope because I've also tried to do something like:

```
{% set flipbook = true %}
{% if flipbook %}
   {% partial 'partial' %}
{% endif %}
... some code
```

This works great. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to pass variables to your partial.  See OctoberCMS documentation : https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/partials#partial-variables

```
 {% partial "partial" flipbook=flipbook %}
```

Inside the partial, variables can be accessed like any other markup
variable:

```
<p>Name: {{ flipbook.name }}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`{% set variableName = 'data' %}` is context-specific, i.e. that variable will only exist within the context that it is set in, unless you pass it to another context as suggested by Pierre-André.

In your case, you want to have access to that variable within your page, not a partial, so you will want to add the variable to the Twig rendering context itself, not just your layout's context. To do that, you will need to make use of the [PHP Section](http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/themes#php-section) of the template to add your variable to the Twig context.

```
url = "/blog"
layout = "default"
==
<?
function onStart()
{
    $this['flipbook'] = true;
}
?>
```

An alternative to all this would be to bundle up your functionality into a [plugin component](http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components) and then just add that component to whatever page needs it.